# Does LAST_N_DAYS:1 Include TODAY?

Tags: soql, date, date-literals

I would like to ask about the definition of [LAST_N_DAYS:n](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm)

> For the number n provided, starts 00:00:00 of the current day and
>   continues for the past n days.

Is

```
CreatedDate = LAST_N_DAYS:1
```

equal to

```
(CreatedDate >= 2017-08-30T00:00:00Z AND CreatedDate <= 2017-08-30T23:59:59Z)
OR CreatedDate  = TODAY
```

and

```
CreatedDate >= YESTERDAY
```

To be more specific, isn't LAST_N_DAYS in fact LAST_N_DAYS + 1 (Today)?

Comment: Nice first question! Looks like the documentation is in fact wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure about salesforce, but in other languages it's common to cast/truncate the time portion away to get just a date, which in this case means that the range starts at 2017-08-31 00:00:00 (which becomes 2017-08-31) and continues for the past 1 days, ending at 2017-08-30 00:00:00 (which is 2017-08-30 when cast to a date).  If it works that way, then starting today (at midnight) and going back 1 day, does in fact give you 2 days worth of time (though I wouldn't consider the documentation wrong... more ambiguous)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In contradiction to what the current documentation claims, you can observe that the `LAST_N_DAYS` date literal **includes today's data**.

To be sure, I ran this query:

```
SELECT CreatedDate FROM MyObject__c
WHERE CreatedDate = LAST_N_DAYS:1
ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1
```

And I got back:

> 2017-08-31T18:16:17.000+0000

Comment: Hmm... the documentation says `For the number n provided, starts 00:00:00 of the current day and continues for the past n days.` Apparently, it lies.

Comment: Right, the documentation is incorrect here.

Comment: The trouble with this is that Salesforce could claim that either the documentation was wrong and correct it or that the platform was not behaving correctly and change the behaviour. Relying on this to cover today is, therefore, potentially risky.

Comment: I certainly never contend you should rely on it including today. However, it is extremely unlikely they would change the behavior and hammer testing should prevent it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I used the following in my `WHERE` clause, and it works as a replacement that operates the same as `LAST_N_DAYS` is documented as expecting to work.

```
SELECT Id
FROM MyObject__c
WHERE CreatedDate = LAST_N_DAYS:n AND CreatedDate < TODAY
```

Explanation: `TODAY` represents a range that "Starts 00:00:00 of the current day and continues for 24 hours." `LAST_N_DAYS:n` is *supposed* to represent a range that, "starts 00:00:00 of the current day and continues for the past n days," but in practice, appears to be the expected range union `TODAY`. Thus, by removing anything that is in the `TODAY` range, we have the expected range.